# Is the census described in Luke’s Gospel connected with the land that the family of Jesus owned in Bethlehem?

Tags: life-of-jesus, nazareth, birth, bethlehem

In [Eusesbius](https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/250103.htm) we have an interesting reference from the 2nd century Christian historian, Hegesippus, to property owned by the family of Jesus:

> But when this same Domitian had commanded that the descendants of
> David should be slain, an ancient tradition says that some of the
> heretics brought accusation against the descendants of Jude (said to
> have been a brother of the Saviour according to the flesh), on the
> ground that they were of the lineage of David and were related to
> Christ himself. Hegesippus relates these facts in the following words.
>
> The Relatives of our Saviour.
>
> 1. Of the family of the Lord there were still living the grandchildren of Jude, who is said to have been the Lord's brother according to the
>    flesh.
> 2. Information was given that they belonged to the family of David, and they were brought to the Emperor Domitian by the Evocatus. For
>    Domitian feared the coming of Christ as Herod also had feared it. And
>    he asked them if they were descendants of David, and they confessed
>    that they were. Then he asked them how much property they had, or how
>    much money they owned. And both of them answered that they had only
>    nine thousand denarii, half of which belonged to each of them.
> 3. And this property did not consist of silver, but of a piece of land which contained only thirty-nine acres, and from which they raised
>    their taxes and supported themselves by their own labor. 5. Then they
>    showed their hands, exhibiting the hardness of their bodies and the
>    callousness produced upon their hands by continuous toil as evidence
>    of their own labor.

Is this a reference to property owned in Bethlehem? If so, was Joseph (Jesus father) land rich (at least middle class), but cash poor when they went to Bethlehem for the census? And again cash poor when bringing the child to the temple to be dedicated?

It is interesting to reflect upon the fifth pope; consecrated about 100; died about 109. The breviary of Pope Pius V. reserves Oct. 26 to the memory of *Evaristus Græcus ex Judæo parte Trajano Imperatore Pontificatum gessit.* From this it would follow that this pope was a Jew, whose father was a native of Bethlehem, and therefore, no doubt, a Roman provincial. Evaristus, then, must have been a Greek-speaking Jew, and, under the laws of the empire, a Roman subject.

Another possibility is that at the time of Emperor Domitian, Jesus' family (i.e. the grandchildren of his brother Jude) owned 39 acres in Nazareth. If my calculations are correct, of those 39 acres of the approximately 60 acres in Nazareth, 65% of the land was owned by Jude’s grandchildren. If so, that's a lot of land owned in Nazareth.

Comment: What may have been owned 200years after Jesus died by descendants of Mary and Joseph  has little bearing on the time Jesus was living.  Mary and Joseph were not wealthy landowners

Comment: Kris, Hegesippus quotes Domitian, who was Roman emperor from 81 to 96 AD. And considering that land was often passed down in a hereditary manner it is likely that Joseph was an ancestral land owner as well.

Comment: @Jess This might explain the need for Joseph to travel to bethlehem for the census.

Comment: I have voted to close this question as it is not about Christianity. I doubt whether SE-History would be interested in such trivial detail but it might be worth a try there.

Comment: Davidlol, that is what I am thinking. It is just controversial because it challenges the narrative of what is usually said about Jesus growing up.

Comment: Nigel, I took your considerations into account and changed my title. Now it is directly related to the Christmas story of the census & the milieu of Jesus growing up.

Comment: Davidlol, ironically I found the reference from Hegesippus while reading Crosan’s “Excavating Jesus.” His assumption is that Jesus grew up poor and illiterate. I’m thinking, among other things, the amount of land owed by his family indicates otherwise.

Comment: Poor yes.      illiterate certainly not